# Trying to capture user input in form and add them into an array and show output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to capture user input from a form by getting the values and then pushing them into an array. I then want to output them with an alert but for some reason the values are getting concatenated instead of added. I also have a random zero with my output. I should be getting the total of the three values (example 1+2+3 should give 6, not 0123. Please advise thanks!

```js
function myFunction() {
    var totalArray = [];
    
    totalArray.push(document.getElementById('votes1').value);
    totalArray.push(document.getElementById('votes2').value);
    totalArray.push(document.getElementById('votes3').value);
    
    var totalAmount = 0;
    
    for (var x = 0; x < totalArray.length; x++) {
    
        totalAmount += totalArray[x];
    }
    
    alert(totalAmount); 
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<input id="votes1" value="1"/>
<input id="votes2" value="2"/>
<input id="votes3" value="3"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use parseInt to convert values to integers before adding them, like this:

```
totalAmount += parseInt(totalArray[x]);
```

Comment: wow duh!! something so easy thank you!! totally overlooked that

Answer (score 2):

The value property `.value` return a string value so you should parse this value to number if you want to  perform any calculation :

```
totalAmount += Number(totalArray[x]);
```

Else the `+` will concatenate the values as strings.

Hope this helps.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var totalArray = [];

  totalArray.push(document.getElementById('votes1').value);
  totalArray.push(document.getElementById('votes2').value);
  totalArray.push(document.getElementById('votes3').value);

  var totalAmount = 0;

  for (var x = 0; x < totalArray.length; x++) {

      totalAmount += Number(totalArray[x]);
  }

  alert(totalAmount); 
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<input id="votes1" value="1"/>
<input id="votes2" value="2"/>
<input id="votes3" value="3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified your code a lil' bit.

```js
const count = () => {
  let totalAmount = 0,
      numberOfInputs = 3;
      
  for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfInputs; i++) {
    totalAmount += Number(document.getElementById(`votes${i}`).value);
  }
  
  console.log(totalAmount); // return
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', count);
```

```html
<input id='votes1'>
<input id='votes2'>
<input id='votes3'>
<button id='btn'>Count</button>
```